# Youtube Encrypted signatures detected

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-dl

I'm researching video patterns, and for that i am required to download videos from youtube.
I've found [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) project very useful for this exactly, as it is a command line tool written in Python (which integrates nicely with the rest of my project which is python on ubuntu based).

Trying to download some videos, I have encountered this issue:

```
me@server:~/Desktop/YouTube/backend$ ./youtube-dl.py https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SbUC-UaAxE
[youtube] Setting language
[youtube] 8SbUC-UaAxE: Downloading video webpage
[youtube] 8SbUC-UaAxE: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] 8SbUC-UaAxE: Extracting video information
[youtube] 8SbUC-UaAxE: Encrypted signatures detected.
ERROR: unable to download video
```

1) Is this because this video is copyright protected?
 
2) Has anybody got experience downloading such videos? I see tools like [Free Video Downloader](http://www.freemake.com/free_video_downloader/) and [this toolbar app](http://apps.conduit.com/musicapps-Music_Browser-app?appid=d5c4c431-a6ed-49fe-9670-df872dce43fe&lang=he) that seems to tackle this just fine. I need to accomplish similar functionality usable within a python web framework, nodejs or alike.

Comment: as your problem is not programming related, it is off-topic for [so]. please check [su] for general computing questions, or the documentation/user-forum for `youtube-dl`

Comment: open the link in your browser and most probably it will tell you the exact reason

Comment: @mnagel Opening this link just lets me watch the video as it normally would.

Comment: @umläute how is this not programming related?

Comment: if you can watch it alright, then the reason why it fails is not "you cannot watch this video in your country" or another permanent failure. it might e.g.  be a temporary failure due to google's rate limiting or an issue within youtube-dl.

Comment: you should probably file a ticket on their (youtube-dl) github project.

Comment: @mnagel i'll do that. also thought maybe someone is familiar with this already.

Comment: maybe someone is, but the percentage and probably the absolute number of knowledgeable people will be higher on the github project page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Resolved.** 
Amazingly enough, this is fixed in an update that came out just [today](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/1439).

in order to fix this, just:

```
sudo youtube-dl -U
```

this will get you on the latest version which has this covered. Cheers.

Comment: if it is resolved, please *accept* the answer (even if it is your own), so the question doesn't show up as "unanswered".

Answer (score 0):

If you are still struggling with this, you can use tube_dl. It contains latest deciphering algos.

```
pip install tube_dl
from tube_dl import Youtube
Youtube('Your URL').Formats()
```

Full documentation can be found here : https://github.com/shekharchander/tube_dl